# Is there a way to make fancyhdr with pagestyle fancy to be compatible with Chinese language?

Tags: fancyhdr, cjk, chinese

I successfully can compile with Chinese characters in my documents using `CJKutf8`. However it makes all my files, that use `fancyhdr` with pagestyle `fanc` to throw encoding related errors during compilation.

Minimal example to reproduce (assuming that cjk support is installed on the system and running):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}               
%\pagestyle{fancy} % <---- uncomment to throw error in compile

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}

\section{前言}

\section{关于数学部分}
数学、中英文皆可以混排。You can intersperse math, Chinese and English (Latin script) without adding extra environments.

\end{CJK*}

\bigskip  %% Just some white space

You can also insert Latin text in your document

\bigskip  %% Just some white space

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi}
這是繁體中文。
\end{CJK*}

\end{document}
```

Example was taken from [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Chinese) and extended.

Uncommenting `\pagestyle{fancy}` produces the following error:

```
! PACKAGE INPUTENC ERROR: UNICODE CHAR Ņ� (U+5173)
(INPUTENC)                NOT SET UP FOR USE WITH LATEX.

SEE THE INPUTENC PACKAGE DOCUMENTATION FOR EXPLANATION.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Now I don't want to use xetex or luatax as workarounds and I also have created some quite complex headers in my documents, which I'd like to keep.

So my question is, if there is a way to resolve this error for example by adding a specific package or configure `fancyhdr` correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These days using luatex or xelatex for non latin scripts is probably recommended but you can re-assert the CJK processing so that it is in scope in the heading. Simpler to hide it in a macro so it is safe from expansion and uppercasing issues.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}               
\pagestyle{fancy} % <---- uncomment to throw error in compile

\protected\def\zzzA{\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}前言\end{CJK*}}
\protected\def\zzzB{\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}关于数学部分\end{CJK*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}

\section{\zzzA}

\section{\zzzB}
数学、中英文皆可以混排。You can intersperse math, Chinese and English (Latin script) without adding extra environments.

\end{CJK*}

\bigskip  %% Just some white space

You can also insert Latin text in your document

\bigskip  %% Just some white space

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi}
這是繁體中文。
\end{CJK*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great simple solution, the macro wrapping works without the need for additional packages.

Answer (score 1):

If you're free to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX and have a suitable system font, i.e., one which has the requisite Chinese characters, you can dispense with switching between `CJK*` and "ordinary" environments.

The following example compiles equally well under both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX on my MacOS system, MacTeX2018, the `fontspec` package, and the SimSun system font.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % for "\setmainfont" macro
\setmainfont{SimSun}  % or some other suitable font
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}  % not needed

\usepackage{fancyhdr}               
\pagestyle{fancy} 

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example

\begin{document}

%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn} % not needed

\section{前言}

\section{关于数学部分}
数学、中英文皆可以混排。You can intersperse math, Chinese and English 
(Latin script) without adding extra environments.

%\end{CJK*} % not needed

\bigskip  %% Just some white space

You can also insert Latin text in your document

\bigskip  %% Just some white space

%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi} % not needed
這是繁體中文。
%\end{CJK*} % not needed

\end{document}
```